How can I tell git to ignore SSL errors only for one specific remote host?
I work in a computing environment where, for reasons beyond my control, attempting to access our git server from our compute cluster results in SSL errors (internal info redacted from ):
$ git ls-remote https://INTERNAL_URL_OF_GIT_REPO
fatal: unable to access 'https://INTERNAL_URL_OF_GIT_REPO': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

However, both servers are behind our company firewall, so I know that the server is ok even if the certificate fails. I know that I can maually disable SSL verification with a command-line argument:
$ git -c http.sslVerify=false ls-remote https://INTERNAL_URL_OF_GIT_REPO
241a414084eb282617dfdd4862ba9d6e51b9916e    HEAD
241a414084eb282617dfdd4862ba9d6e51b9916e    refs/heads/main

And I further know that I could permanently set this option as default by doing git config --global http.sslVerify false. But I very much don't want to do this since it would globally disable all SSL verification. Even setting this option for the repo is too much. What I really want is to disable SSL verification just for a single remote URL. Is there any way to configure this?

just fix the cert.  It's the easiest and safest solution.  "both servers are behind our company firewall, so I know that the server is ok even if the certificate fails" personally I don't find that reassuring.

@erik258 As I mentioned, the certificate is not under my control. I'm trying to get it fixed, but there's no guarantee, so I would like to know if there is a workaround. (Specifically, a workaround that doesn't require me to selectively add -c http.sslVerify=false to every git command that interacts with this server while avoiding adding it to any other git command.)

As a follow-up, my IT department advised me to disable the SSL verification for this server, since it's only an internal server. This is more or less the response I expected, so unfortunately I do indeed need to selectively disable SSL in order to get my work done.

"since it's only an internal server" kindly note that your IT department doesn't understand that HTTP protects you from connecting to the wrong server, so it doesn't matter that the right server is internal.  Furthermore if they don't realize fixing the cert is simpler and faster than talking about it, they're incompetent or at the very least naive.

Any of the http.* options can be applied selectively to some URLs. See the docs. Do
git config --global http.https://INTERNAL_URL_OF_GIT_REPO.sslVerify false

